# In TableLayoutPanel if Dock = Fill and AutoSize = true then last column/row occupy all remaining space

Tags: winforms

In TableLayoutPanel if we set AutoSize = true and Dock = fill
then last column/row will occupy all remaining space.
How to set it to required height (row) and width (column)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `TableLayoutPanel` as tbl1 with two rows and two columns. Then set `dock = fill autoscroll = true` and set width for 1st row to `autosize` and for the second `absolute 0.00 F`.

Do the same for column 1 and 2.
Now add actual `TableLayoutPanel` in 1st rows 1st column.

Comment: What worked for me was -- add a dummy (invisible) component to the TableLayoutPanel, forcing a new row, and live with the (now invisible, besides a small glitch regarding scrollbar visibility) behavior.

Answer (score 8):

I just added an additional last row and set its size to Absolute and 0 pixel. This worked for me.

Comment: any idea why it is working for a last row but not for a last column?

Answer (score 2):

To complete the answer of @user232986 that helped me solve my issue.
This is code for `VB.NET`
In the designer I selected for

- Row1: `AutoSize` (Containing data like a Label for example)
- Row2: `AutoSize` (Containing data like a Panel for example)
- Row3: `Percent 100%` (This is the last row containing data)
- Row4: `Absolute 0` (Add a dummy row)

Then in my code I changed this settings and it worked like a charm.

```
Me.tableLay.AutoSizeMode = Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
Me.tableLay.AutoSize = True
Me.tableLay.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
```

I only have a single column which is set to `Percent 100,00%`.